# Increase swap memory in Rancher or Podman with Mac Apple Sillicon

Tags: docker, memory, swap, rancher

Recently, due to company policies, I was asked to stop using Docker, so my alternative was Podman or Rancher.

Currently I am trying to use Rancher, but when building an image from a DockerFile there is a certain process that requires swap memory and that's when I get this error

```
Checking swap space: 0 MB available, 500 MB required.    Failed <<<<

Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before

continuing with the installation,
```

In Docker Desktop there was an option to increase this type of memory, however Rancher does not have it and after trying many things I can not increase this memory.

I have read that it is not possible on my Mac with M1 but I am not sure.

Also i have tried making this partion manually

```bash
[izavala@macos]:~ $ top -l 1 | grep "PhysMem\|Swap"

PhysMem: 31G used (1988M wired, 3237M compressor), 156M unused.

[izavala@macos]:~ $ sudo /opt/homebrew/Cellar/util-linux/2.39.3/sbin/mkswap /tmp/swapfile
sudo /opt/homebrew/Cellar/util-linux/2.39.3/sbin/swapon /tmp/swapfile

Password:
mkswap: /tmp/swapfile: warning: wiping old swap signature.
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 1024 MiB (1073725440 bytes)
no label, UUID=1471b57b-6eb6-462f-a803-efa273c7d84c
sudo: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/util-linux/2.39.3/sbin/swapon: command not found
```

but `swapon` is not found after installing

```
brew install util-linux
```

Also i tried to build image with this flags but still not working

```
nerdctl build --build-arg MEMORY=2G --build-arg MEMORY_SWAP=4G -t image-name:v2 --platform linux/amd64 .
```